# runtime expansion of uitableview footerview using autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UIView that is a footerview of a uitableview. At run time, the user enters text into a uitextview within the footerview that should adjust to the size of the text content with a height constraint in autolayout.

All other objects in the view (labels, imageviews) have appropriate constraints to accommodate the expansion of the textview.

HOWEVER the height of the overall footerview will not change size, and it is impossible to use autolayout on the tableview footerview height.

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Haven't found an actual, elegant, solution yet, but I've postponed fixing this by using a workaround:
Setting the frame of the view used as a footer to be as large as you might possible need. In my case this meant giving it about 60px of spare vertical room. Since it's the footer and there's nothing below it to reposition the user won't be affected by the workaround.
The contents of the footer view are pinned to the top and have enough space to expand when needed.
For the record: my view is loaded from a nib file.
Although in theory the size one gives to the top level view in interface builder is just for design-time and the runtime size should be calculated based on constraints and the resulting intrinsic size, for this specific case I found the height stays the same as it was in IB.

Answer (score 1):

We can change the height of the footer view run time by the following code:

```
func methodToChangeTableViewFooterHeight()
{
    var footerView:UIView = self._tableView.tableFooterView! as UIView
    var frame:CGRect = footerView.frame
    frame.size.height = self.heightCollectionCS.constant + 10
    footerView.frame = frame
    self._tableView.tableFooterView! = footerView
}
```

Here , self.heightCollectionCS.constant is the height constraint for our Collection View. 
We can use  text content height on that place.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set again the footer view each time you footer height changes, to inform the table it should change the footer height. Or use inset. From within the footer view:

```
SetNeedsLayout()
LayoutIfNeeded()
ownertable.TableFooterView = this
```

Comment: Could you please expand on the above method? What I tried is set the footer first and then add constraints via code. This worked fine in iOS 8 but in iOS 7 it crashes. Seems that the tableviews implementation of viewDidLayoutSubViews doesn't call super. Please help.

Comment: Yes on iOS 7, autolayout is not supported on every part of every control.

Comment: So how do you suggest to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, misread that question long ago. You can access the footer directly through the tableview's property `tableFooterView`.

What you could do is create your default footer in a xib or in your `viewDidLoad:`. Once you need to increase the size of the footer, you can pull out the `UIView` from that property and edit its frame if necessary to make it larger.

So make sure the `tableFooterView` gets assigned a `UIView` because it is nil by default. To just make the height taller, you can use `self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame = CGRectMake(whatever rect you need);`

Comment: And what would the section number be for the TABLE footer?